# setVisibility GONE not Work in Listview Android

Tags: android, listview, adapter, visible

i get problem in my code...
i want to setVisibility Gone all Image from custom my list view...
i tried but is not work :(

this my code...

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        DatabaseHandler database = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        List<Setting_App> isisetting_appListSqllite = database.getSettingApp("Hide Image");

        String hide_image;
        if(isisetting_appListSqllite.size()>0){
            Setting_App s = isisetting_appListSqllite.get(0);
            hide_image = s.getIsiSettingApp();              
        }
        else{
            hide_image="N";
        }

        int count_list_adapter=list.getAdapter().getCount()-2;
        if(adapter!=null){
        for(int i=2; i < count_list_adapter; i++){  

            ImageView thumb_image= (ImageView)list.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null).
                    findViewById(R.id.image_tulisan);

            if(hide_image.equals("Y")){
                thumb_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
            }

            else{
                thumb_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    }
    }
```

how to fix it ?
thanks your partisipation... sorry with my english...

Comment: i guess "does not work" means it crashes, because that's what it should do. getView is not supposed to be called by you. You are supposed to do something in the adapter to make it hide the images.

Answer (score 2):

Adapter `getView()` does not return those views that are visible on the screen. Calling it this way creates new views that are not shown anywhere.

Instead, implement the image hiding in your adapter's `getView()`. To force a refresh of the listview, call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.